# Add a timeout to a submit form (JSP)

Tags: java

So, I want to limit a user from submitting a form over and over again, a example is they submit a form, they need to wait 20 seconds until they can submit it again, I know you can do this in JS, however I am not familiar with JS, I would like to do this in Java so I can implement it in my own way.

I was thinking of getting the time of the last submit and if x amount of seconds have not passed it would return a error, is there a more simple way off doing this?

Comment: What is your backend? Old school Servlet or some design patterns like spring-boot?

Comment: The most feasible solution is to use Session. When the form submitted for the first time, update the timestamp in the session and later in every submit check that value. However I'm afraid for a proper user experience (like showing a counter), you need to do a little bit of JS.

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam Servlets (Java EE).

Comment: @madz thats unfortunate, well thanks, I will give it a shot!